# #ifdef doesn't seem to work with my framework

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a framework that uses two other frameworks, all of which I have made myself.

One of the used frameworks has a few classes with an #ifdef NEED_THIS_CLASS #endif around it with a #define NEED_THIS_CLASS in it's .pch file.

The reason for this is that I use the framework for most of my apps, but if these classes are included, which are a part of the framework, it can be rejected in the app store if the classes are not used. So I outcomment the #define when I don't need it and use it if I do, this has worked without a problem.

The problem is now that I want to use it in another framework where I need to use these classes, it doesn't seem to be able to find the classes. It's as if the #define NEED_THIS_CLASS is not there.

I can fix it by removing the #ifdef #endif around the classes, so it doesn't seem to be a problem with some referencing. It can find it if the #ifdef isn't there, and I can use all the other classes in the framework just fine. But it's alot more convenient to only have to change it in one place instead of 6 places if I need/don't need these classes.

Anyone have experience with #ifdef #endif in frameworks inside frameworks who has a solution to my problem? Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

The framework has to be compiled with the option, as it's just a glorified shared library. Once you add the framework to the project, it is already done compiling and whatever your compile time settings and switches are, they won't affect the binary that has already been generated for the framework.

Comment: But I add the framework project of the used framework to the framework, so I can use the product of the framework project as the Linked Frameworks and Libraries, so when I try to build my framework it builds the framework again, with current settings. At least that's how I assume it works :)

Comment: @Hafax Ah, I see. In that case though, your Framework is not going to build with your projects prefix header but either with its own or none. Make it a global define through the compiler in that case.

Comment: It seems to not use a prefix header at all. It worked though if I added it as a Preprocessor Macro on the frameworks build settings, but I'd prefer it would work with the used framework's prefix header. Is there a way to force it to use the used framework's prefix header? Or even force it to use the project's own prefix header?